# can't browse to a .cs file in a WCF service

Tags: wcf

I'm running my WCF service program. This error has occurred; how can it be solved?

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.cs' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /IService1.cs
>   Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.1433; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.1433

Answer (score 1):

You aren't deploying your service correctly, you should be using .asmx/.svc files and dlls.  You probably need to walk through a [MSDN WCF Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx)

Here is another good [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx) explaining the Hosting of WCF Services